# Having issues rotating facebook, twitter, and youtube icon images

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, transform

I'am working on website for my friend to improve my skills, but....I' am having a problem with rotating the social-media-icons via javascript. I get an error in javascript console saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null ". What I'am doing wrong?

Here is the following HTML and javascript code.

index.html ------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

    <head>
        <script src="js/icon_app.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ranks.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="Resources/The_Seven_Nobles_icon.ico">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The Seven Nobles | Kingdom RP-PVP Guild on WoW PTR | RP-Community</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="body-container">
            <header id="container-header">
                <div id="header-left">
<a href="index.html" class="homepage_pic">
<img src="Resources/tsn_header2.jpg" alt="tsn_header2 picture">
</a>

                </div>
                <div id="header-right2">
                    <img src="Resources/Social-Network-Facebook-icon.png" alt="icon" width="40" height="40" id="facebook-social-media-icons" />
                    <img src="Resources/social-twitter-box-blue-icon.png" alt="icon" width="40" height="40" id="twitter-social-media-icons" />
                    <img src="Resources/youtube-icon.jpg" alt="icon" width="40" height="40" id="youtube-social-media-icons">
                    <p>Click and visit us</p>
                </div>
            </header>
            <nav id="headerNav">
                <ul id="top-navBar">
                    <li class="home"><a href="#"> </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lore </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ranks </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Quiz</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="main-content">
                <div id="content-summary">
                    <section id="getStarted">

<h4 class="header-topics0">Get started</h4>

                        <p>Welcome to our guild website. Before you join the guild on the World of Warcraft Public Test Realm, please make sure to read about the Guild lore, and take the online challenge quiz to test your knowledge of our guild. Go fourth and venture a new world Little Nobles! GO GO GO!</p>
                    </section>
                    <section id="goal-accessment">

<h4 class="header-topics1">Goal Accessments</h4>

                        <p>Welcome to our guild website. Before you join the guild on the World of Warcraft Public Test Realm, please make sure to read about the Guild lore, and take the online challenge quiz to test your knowledge of our guild. Go fourth and venture a new world Little Nobles! GO GO GO!</p>
                    </section>
                    <section id="contribute-now">

<h4 class="header-topics2">Contribute Now</h4>

                        <p>Welcome to our guild website. Before you join the guild on the World of Warcraft Public Test Realm, please make sure to read about the Guild lore, and take the online challenge quiz to test your knowledge of our guild. Go fourth and venture a new world Little Nobles! GO GO GO!</p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <div id="content-summary-below">
                    <section id="guild-founders">
                        <p id="founders-name">THE TSN PROJECT IS FOUNDED BY</p>
<span>Joseph Bourne & Kurobank</span>

                        <p id="founders-quote">Productive Front-End Web Technology</p>
<a id="get-started-button" href="#">Get Started</a>

                        <p id="copyright-letter">Copyright TSN, is a trademark of TSN, Inc.
<a href="#" target="_blank">View License</a>

                        </p>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <footer id="footer-content">
                    <ul id="support-list">
                        <li class="list-header"><a href="#">Support</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Support Articles</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Parental Controls</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help! I got hacked!</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="developer-list">
                        <li class="list-header"><a href="#">Developers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">API</li>
<li><a href="#">Source Code</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Development Team</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="career-list">
                        <li class="list-header"><a href="#">Career</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Work at TSN</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Search for job</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Open Position</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jobs FAQ</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">University Relations</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

icon_app.js ------------------------------------------------

```
function rotateNow(el, degs) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.Tranform = degs;
}

var myVar1 = setInterval(rotateNow("facebook-social-media-icons", "rotate(70deg)"), 1000);
var myVar2 = setInterval(rotateNow("twitter-social-media-icons", "rotate(20deg)"), 1000);
var myVar3 = setInterval(rotateNow("youtube-social-media-icons", "rotate(90deg)"), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reasons can be that you are running the script early, even before the page is fully loaded. The reason for error is that the line `document.getElementById(el)` cannot find the specified element so it returns `null` and when you access `style` of `null` , it throws error.

Try placing your js at the end of the page.

Secondly, you have a spelling mistake in `elem.style.Tranform = degs`, its `elem.style.transform = degs` . Also, you need to be careful about specifying browser specific styles ie `webkitTransform`, `mozTransform` etc.

After the correction, it will work fine for you:

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/168/

JS:

```
    function rotateNow(el, degs) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.WebkitTransform = degs;
    elem.style.MozTransform = degs;
    elem.style.transform = degs;
    elem.style.OTransform = degs;
    elem.style.msTransform = degs;
}

setInterval(function () {
    rotateNow("facebook-social-media-icons", "rotate(70deg)");
    rotateNow("twitter-social-media-icons", "rotate(20deg)");
    rotateNow("youtube-social-media-icons", "rotate(90deg)")
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Sigh.....I' am such an idiot lol, I should've been known that. Funny part is i was reading on blog and it mention how javascript developers load their scripts at the bottom; let alone, whenever I inspect source code of site, I notice they put script tag at bottom. THX for the help.